# Conditionally show/hide divs based on select option in AMP

Tags: onchange, amp-html

I am developing my first AMP site and would like to know if it's possible to show/hide multiple divs on:change based on user selection, like so.

```
<div class="ampstart-input" id="index">
    <select name="product_type" id="product_type" required>
        <option value="type_one">Type one</option>
        <option value="type_two">Type two</option>
        <option value="type_three">Type three</option>
        <option value="type_four">Type four</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="loan" id="type_one" hidden">Content for product one</div>
<div class="loan" id="type_two" hidden">Content for product two</div>
<div class="loan" id="type_three" hidden">Content for product three</div>
<div class="loan" id="type_four" hidden">Content for product four</div>
```

When the user changes the select field, I'd like to be able to show the selected product, and hide the others (and possibly hide the original select #index). This is familiar and simple in JavaScript, but I can't find any way to achieve it in AMP. Any help would be VERY appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for your help, this jsbin resolves it. Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My AMP Page</title>
  <link rel="canonical" href="self.html" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <select on="change:AMP.setState({ activeDiv: event.value })">
    <option value=0></option>
    <option value=1>Div 1</option>
    <option value=2>Div 2</option>
  </select>
  <div hidden [hidden]="activeDiv != 1">
    Div 1
  </div>
  <div hidden [hidden]="activeDiv != 2">
    Div 2
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/joxufigovo/edit?html,output

Answer (score -3):

Yes You can do it with simple jquery. try it will work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Try jQuery Online</title>

    <style>
        .selected { 
            color:red; 
        }
        .highlight { 
            background:yellow; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ampstart-input" id="index">
        <select name="product_type" id="product_type">
            <option value="type_one">Type one</option>
            <option value="type_two">Type two</option>
            <option value="type_three">Type three</option>
            <option value="type_four">Type four</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="loan" id="type_one" >Content for product one</div>
    <div class="loan" id="type_two">Content for product two</div>
    <div class="loan" id="type_three">Content for product three</div>
    <div class="loan" id="type_four">Content for product four</div>
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("hello");
      $('#product_type').on('change', function() {
        $('.loan').each(function(i, obj) {
            $(this).css('display','none');
        });
        var select_val = $("#product_type option:selected").val();
        $("#"+select_val ).css('display','block');

    });
  });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to do this in AMP, and javascript / jquery or other external libraries and frameworks aren't permitted by AMP.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but AMP has not supported the Jquery or any javascript